# MVC3 binding nested model using Entity Framework with GUID keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, nested-forms, model-binding

I have been fighting with this all day and still I am failing.

I can simplify the problem as follows:
I have reports and reports have forms. I have entity models of each. They have Guid id's as shown below.

[image: Model]

I am trying to get a single view where I can create a report and a form. As an end goal I would like to be able to add multiple forms, but just one would be great. My controller is as follows:

```
    // GET: /AllInOne/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.PossibleReportBases = reportBaseRepository.All;
        ViewBag.PossibleCategories = categoryRepository.All;

        var model = new Report {FromDate = DateTime.Now};
        model.Forms.Add(new Form());
        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: /AllInOne/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Report report)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            reportRepository.InsertOrUpdate(report);
            reportRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.PossibleReportBases = reportBaseRepository.All;
            ViewBag.PossibleCategories = categoryRepository.All;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The repository code looks like this:

```
    public void InsertOrUpdate(Report report)
    {
        if (report.Id == default(System.Guid)) {
            // New entity
            report.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            context.Reports.AddObject(report);
        } else {
            // Existing entity
            context.Reports.Attach(report);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(report, EntityState.Modified);
        }
    }
```

At one stage the binding was giving me this error:
The EntityCollection has already been initialized. The InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph.

I have tried many things for the views, but none of them have worked.

Please help.

Comment: Is the problem in creating the views or with saving the report posted back to the server? If the latter is the case: Can you show the code inside of `reportRepository.InsertOrUpdate(report)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont' think you need to bother with the attaching.  if you've selected the report from your context, it is already being tracked.  you can simplify your repository like so

```
   public void InsertOrUpdate(Report report)
    {
        // i prefer Guid.Empty but no big deal
        if (report.Id == default(System.Guid)) {
            // New entity
            report.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            context.Reports.AddObject(report);
        } 
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: I agree 100% with the above. The problem, however, is getting the report and form bound into the same model from a view. For some reason I cannot get them to bind properly.

Comment: I don't think that a web page in a user's browser will have a tracking context. The report comes into the controller as a detached object.

Comment: @TheGwa: Is the problem that the `Forms` collection (or reference) in your `report` object (which is passed into the Create post action) is `null`? I still don't understand what's exactly your problem.

Comment: @Slauma: Error message: The EntityCollection has already been initialized. The InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph.

Comment: oh, i think i understand, the nested form object isn't getting posted back to your action.  i would suggest you write a separate View that handles the form updates, and include a hidden variable "ReportId" that is the foreign key to the parent Report.

Comment: I think the problem is with the model binding. I can't seem to get the report and the form from one view. I am going for something like this. http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: @Jason: The new Report does not have an Id yet in the create part.

Comment: well then rework your action method to accept a Report and a Form as separate parameters, combine them before saving -- e.g. Create(Report report, Form form).

Comment: @Jason: That is an option, but in the end there will be many other classes deeply nested. This is just an over simplification. I think the answer may be to bite the bullet and build it out in json. What do you think?

Comment: I think you should re-think your UI so users are only working with one discrete entity at a time.  Monolithic forms are no fun to full out and validation will be a nightmare.

Comment: @TheGwa: You should really edit such important info like the exception message into your question so that other readers get a complete overview. Possibly model binding isn't your problem at all. The exception says that someone calls `InitializeRelatedCollection` during deserialization. Who should call this if not the modelbinder? (In other words: It *tries* to bind the related objects but it fails.) The problem might well be that you directly use `EntityObject` derived entities in your view (and not POCO entities or ViewModels).